# Adding support when generating g-code from Cura Engine (command line)?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, g-code, support-structures

Is it possible to use Cura Engine (the command line tool) to generate a gcode with support?

Here is what I do now:

```
CuraEngine slice -j /usr/share/cura/resources/definitions/ultimaker2.def.json -l my.stl -o my.gcode
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this in the fdrmprinter.def.json which you could might make a copy of and use instead for the -j option:

```
"support":
    {
        "label": "Support",
        "type": "category",
        "icon": "category_support",
        "description": "Support",
        "children":
        {
            "support_enable":
            {
                "label": "Enable Support",
                "description": "Enable support structures. These structures support$
                "type": "bool",
                "default_value": false,
                "settable_per_mesh": true,
                "settable_per_extruder": false
            }
        }
    }
```

Change the "default_value" under "support_enable" to true and that could work.